# Fetch data from JSON Category wise

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I am writing an app in which i am **fetching data from JSON**, and i am able to fetch **list of Categories** but whenever i do click on any of the Category **not getting List of Products** under that particular Category always **getting Blank activity**.

**JSON:**

```
[
{
"categoryId": "1",
"categoryTitle": "SmartPhones", "SmartPhones": [
        {
            "itemId": "1",
            "itemTitle": "Galaxy Mega 5.8"
        },
        {
            "itemId": "2",
            "itemTitle": "Galaxy Mega 6.3"
        }
    ]
},
{
"categoryId": "2",
"categoryTitle": "Tablets", "Tablets": [
        {
            "itemId": "1",
            "itemTitle": "Galaxy Note 510"
        },
        {
            "itemId": "2",
            "itemTitle": "Galaxy Note 800"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

**AlbumsActivity.java [using for Categories]:**

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray albums = null;

    // albums JSON url
    private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "my.json"; //providing proper URL

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_ID = "categoryId";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "categoryTitle";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check for internet connection
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Hashmap for ListView
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
        new LoadAlbums().execute();

        // get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        /**
         * Listview item click listener
         * TrackListActivity will be lauched by passing album id
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // on selecting a single album
                // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

                // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
                String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });     
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
     * */
    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Listing Albums ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Albums JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {               
                albums = new JSONArray(json);

                if (albums != null) {
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        albumsList.add(map);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                            R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**TrackListActivity.java [using for Products]:**

```
public class TrackListActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tracksList;

    // tracks JSONArray
    JSONArray albums = null;

    // Album id
    String album_id, album_name;

    // tracks JSON url
    // id - should be posted as GET params to get track list (ex: id = 5)
    private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "my.json"; //providing proper url

    // ALL JSON node names

    private static final String TAG_ID = "itemId";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "itemTitle";
    private static final String TAG_ALBUM = "categoryId";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracks);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(TrackListActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Get album id
        Intent i = getIntent();
        album_id = i.getStringExtra("album_id");

        // Hashmap for ListView
        tracksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading tracks in Background Thread
        new LoadTracks().execute();

        // get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        /**
         * Listview on item click listener
         * SingleTrackActivity will be lauched by passing album id, song id
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // On selecting single track get song information
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleTrackActivity.class);

                // to get song information
                // both album id and song is needed
                String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                String song_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_id)).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Album Id: " + album_id  + ", Song Id: " + song_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);
                i.putExtra("song_id", song_id);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        }); 

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all tracks under one album
     * */
    class LoadTracks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TrackListActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading songs ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting tracks json and parsing
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // post album id as GET parameter
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ID, album_id));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Track List JSON: ", json);

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jObj != null) {
                    String album_id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);
                    album_name = jObj.getString(TAG_ALBUM);


                    if (albums != null) {
                        // looping through All songs
                        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String song_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put("album_id", album_id);
                            map.put(TAG_ID, song_id);                           
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            tracksList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all tracks
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            TrackListActivity.this, tracksList,
                            R.layout.list_item_tracks, new String[] { "album_id", TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.album_id, R.id.song_id, R.id.album_name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                    // Change Activity Title with Album name
                    setTitle(album_name);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the JSON from the webservice into a `JSONObject` however the JSON you have posted is a `JSONArray`. Try something like this to parse your JSON...

```
            JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);
            if (jObj != null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject cat = jObj.getJSONObject(i);
                   String id = cat.getString("categoryId");
                   String title = cat.getString("categoryTitle");
                   JSONArray devices = cat.optJSONArray(title, null);

                   for(int j=0; i<devices.length(); j++) {
                       //get itemId and itemTitle
                   }
                }
            }
```