# Can not load data to ListView in Activity

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using json to load data in Activity class with content following as:

My Activity class:

```
public class CategoryCarActivity extends ListActivity {

ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<Category> carsList = new ArrayList<Category>();
JSONArray manufacturers = null;
String manufacturer_id, manufacturer_name;
private static final String URL_MANUFACTURERS = "MyURL";
// ALL JSON node names
private static final String TAG_CARS = "cars";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_MANUFACTURER = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(CategoryCarActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }
    Intent i = getIntent();
    manufacturer_id = i.getStringExtra("id");

    carsList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    // Loading tracks in Background Thread
    new LoadTracks().execute();

    // get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    /**
     * Listview on item click listener
     * SingleTrackActivity will be lauched by passing manufacturer id, car id
     * */
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // On selecting single track get car information
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailListCarActivity.class);
            // to get car information
            // both manufacturer id and car is needed
            String manufacturer_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
            String car_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_id)).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Manufacturer Id: " + manufacturer_id  + ", Car Id: " + car_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            i.putExtra("manufacturer_id", manufacturer_id);
            i.putExtra("car_id", car_id);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all tracks under one album
 * */
class LoadTracks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryCarActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading selected car ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting tracks json and parsing
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // post album id as GET parameter
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ID, manufacturer_id));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_MANUFACTURERS, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Category List JSON: ", json);

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            if (jObj != null) {
                String manufacturer_id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);
                manufacturer_name = jObj.getString(TAG_MANUFACTURER);
                manufacturers = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CARS);

                if (manufacturers != null) {
                    // looping through All cars
                    for (int i = 0; i < manufacturers.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = manufacturers.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        // track no - increment i value
                        String track_no = String.valueOf(i + 1);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        // HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Category category = new Category();
                        category.setManufacturer_id(manufacturer_id);
                        category.setId(id);
                        category.setName(name);
                        category.setPrice(price);

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        /*
                        map.put("manufacturer_id", manufacturer_id);                    // note here
                        map.put(TAG_ID, car_id);
                        map.put("track_no", track_no + ".");
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                        */
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        // carsList.add(map);
                        carsList.add(category);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Manufacturers: ", "null");
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(
                CategoryCarActivity.this,     // the context
                R.layout.list_item_categorys, // Simple list item - will toString() your data
                carsList                       // The arraylist
        );

        // updating listview
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
   }
}
```

list_item_categorys.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturer_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Song id / Hidden by default -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/car_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/track_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturer_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/track_no"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:textColor="#9ed321" />
```

I have debugged and check Logcat and see that data has loaded and everything normal, but don't know why data can not load to ListView

**updated**
Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.totoroads.android.app, PID: 4697
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
```

How to fix this problem?? thank you

Comment: you never set an adapter on your listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>[This code looks really similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141256/fetch-data-from-json-category-wise)... maybe copy the rest of it?</sup>

You need an Adapter for your data.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all tracks
    pDialog.dismiss();

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(
        CategoryCarActivity.this,     // the context
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // Simple list item - will toString() your data
        carList                       // The arraylist
    );

    // updating listview
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

You can also make a subclass of `ArrayAdapter<Category>` if you really want to customize a layout.

Comment: sorry I reply for slow, I have updated adapter and it happened an alert, I have update code as above

Comment: Your code looks nothing like my answer... Looks like you attempted to use a  `SimpleAdapter`

Comment: @luongkhanh Try following [this guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter).

Comment: I don't use simple_list_item_1.xml, I use list_item_categorys.xml

Comment: please see onPostExecute() method and Logcat, it has been simpler. I want to replace android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to android.R.layout.list_item_categorys

Comment: @luongkhanh You can't without subclassing the `ArrayAdapter` class, as I linked to in my last comment

Comment: Also, this answer will probably work. You should stop editing your post with new problems. It is recommended you create new posts for new errors/problems.

Answer (score 2):

You're not providing your list to the list view. You need to add your list to your list view with an adapter. This tutorial should help walk you through the process. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

In your postExecute of your asyncTask you can than call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). And your view will update with the new list content.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Ben's answer, you need to set the list to the listview adapter *after* the asynctask completes its background functionality i.e in *onPostExecute()* method of the asynctask.

Comment: The list doesn't need passed, it is a member variable of the activity

Comment: Yea, the second part only then, modifying my answer.

Comment: Actually you don't need to set the list to the adapter after the asynctask. You can set it before and just call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter. Assuming the list is a class variable that you update when the result comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Need to set the list view as suggested by Ben in onPostExecute().

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Its a ListActivity, so just `getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`